# How can I pass mochas done callback function to another helper function

Tags: javascript, callback, promise, mocha.js

I have a block of code that I will be using several times within a then statement in mocha so I turned it into a function. However I also need to call `done()`within that function and it's out of scope resulting in the error **Uncaught ReferenceError: done is not defined**. Here's a code snippet:

```
var collectionChecker = function(results) {
  expect(Array.isArray(results), 'Did not return collection');
  expect(results.length === numAttr, 'Returned wrong number of models');
  done();
};

test('returns a collection with correct number of models', function(done) {
  attrs.getAttributeTemplates().then(collectionChecker);
});
```

How can I pass `done()` to my function?

I found a workaround by chaining another .then and calling done there but it seems like an ugly way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking it - mocha supports promises, you can return a promise and if it is fulfilled the test will pass (and if the expects throw it will fail):

```
var collectionChecker = function(results) {
  expect(Array.isArray(results), 'Did not return collection');
  expect(results.length === numAttr, 'Returned wrong number of models');
};

// just add a return, no `done` here or anywhere    
test('returns a collection with correct number of models', function() {
  return attrs.getAttributeTemplates().then(collectionChecker);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. I was trying to do something similar in another test and it wasn't working as expected. I was trying to return a chain of thens and it was always evaluating to true despite success or failure of the expect within the innermost then. Any suggestion on how to handle that situation?

Comment: @novacog if you have a specific case please open a new question, I promise to take a look.