# How can I chain multiple thens in mocha without using a done callback

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js

In mocha you can use a done callback to keep mocha from running tests until you have called done() to signal that all promises have returned. In some cases using done is problematic. I was told that I can return a promise that will essentially have the same effect as using done. It will resolve after expect result in success or failure (and if the expects throw the test will fail). However this fails when I start chaining multiple thens together and results in the test passing even if the expect fails.

Example with done that works as expected(test fails):

```
test('resync returns true upon success', function(done){
            Models.Asset.Load(this.testId).then(function(asset){
                asset.refresh().then(function(results){
                    expect(results !== null, "returns null, should return true");
                    expect(results.result === true, "does not return true");    
                    done();
                });
            });
        });
```

Example returning a promise instead of using done that always results in the test passing:

```
test('resync returns true upon success', function(){
            return Models.Asset.Load(this.testId).then(function(asset){
                asset.refresh().then(function(results){
                    expect(results !== null, "returns null, should return true");
                    expect(results.result === true, "does not return true");    
                });
            });
        });
```

I assume that the return is returning the results of the first promise which will always be true instead of returning the final result of the chain which should be the expect failing.

For reference here is my previous question in which this method was explained to me:

[How can I pass mochas done callback function to another helper function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338950/how-can-i-pass-mochas-done-callback-function-to-another-helper-function/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you test was failing because, `asset.refresh()` returns a promise, but you are returning it and the default return being `undefined` your test cases are passing.
solution:

```
    test('resync returns true upon success', function(){
        return Models.Asset.Load(this.testId).then(function(asset){
            return asset.refresh().then(function(results){      // Line CHANGED, return added.
                expect(results !== null, "returns null, should return true");
                expect(results.result === true, "does not return true");    
            });
        });
    });
```

alternative:

```
    test('resync returns true upon success', function(){
        return Models.Asset.Load(this.testId).then(function(asset){
            return asset.refresh();
        }).then(function(results){
            expect(results !== null, "returns null, should return true");
            expect(results.result === true, "does not return true");    
        });;
    });
```

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Made the changes and everything works as expected now. Thank you!